# How cast Generic T to Action<...> to get the Method params

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, action, code-generation

Hi i'm try to cast a generic to an Action with a unknown number and type of Parameters

at the moment it looks like:

```
public class subscriber
{        
     public subscriber()
     {
        new Subscription<Action>(a);
        new Subscription<Action<string>>(b);
        new Subscription<Action<int,string>>(c);
     } 

     private void a() { }
     private void b(string gg){}
     private void c(int i, string g) { } 
}


public class Subscription<T>
{    
        public T MyAction {get {retun _action;}}
        public Type MyActionType {get;private set;}

        public Subscription( T action )
        {    
            MyAction  = action;
            MyActionType  = action.GetType();


        var gg = action.GetType().GetGenericArguments();// Contains the Sub generics
        }
}
```

at the moment we know it will be an Action and we also know the Sub Types but how to put this all together
to execute my `private void c(int i, string g)` method

### Final Goal

is to execute the `Action` from a `Third-Class` (which will contains a `List<Subscription>` ) when a `Fourth-Class` hand over some params

Comment: 3rd class cannot contain `List<Subscription>` it can contain `List<Subscription<Action<string>>` or `List<Subscription<Action>>` and parameters of action will be known for 3rd class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public abstract class SubscriptionBase
{
    public abstract void ExecuteAction(params object[] parameters);
}

public class Subscription<T> : SubscriptionBase
{
    private T _action;

    public Subscription(T a)
    {
        _action = a;
    }

    public override void ExecuteAction(params object[] parameters)
    {
        (_action as Delegate).DynamicInvoke(parameters);
    }
}
```

and you can use it like;

```
Action<int> func1 = (q) => q += 1;
Action<int, int> func2 = (q, w) => q += w;

Subscription<Action<int>> s1 = new Subscription<Action<int>>(func1);
Subscription<Action<int, int>> s2 = new Subscription<Action<int, int>>(func2);

List<SubscriptionBase> subscriptionBase = new List<SubscriptionBase>();
subscriptionBase.Add(s1);
subscriptionBase.Add(s2);

subscriptionBase[1].ExecuteAction(1, 2);
```

Comment: This has at least two grave disadvantages: (1) The caller is responsible for checking that the count and types of parameters match. (2) I can pass anything into the constructor of `Subscription`, even an `int`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you are right; but OP does not give much detail about what he is trying to do.

Comment: i'm try to bulid a Mediator

Comment: after some tests i think your answer is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @DanielHilgarth (1) That's exactly what i want ;-)  (2) I can catch this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. You can't put a `Subscription<Action<int>>` into the same list as `Subscription<Action<string, Foo>>`.

I suggest, you create an interface like the following and store those in your third class:

```
interface IActionExecutor
{
    bool CanExecuteForParameters(params object[] parameters);
    void Execute(params object[] parameters);
}

// Implementation for one parameter
// You need to create one class per additional parameter.
// This is similar to the Action delegates in the framework.
// You can probably extract a base class here that implements
// some of the repetitive pars
public class ActionExecutor<in T> : IActionExecutor
{
    private Action<T> _action;

    public ActionExecutor(Action<T> action)
    {
        if(action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecuteForParameters(params object[] parameters)
    {
        if(parameters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        if(parameters.Length != 1) return false;
        return parameters[0] is T;
    }

    public void Execute(params object[] parameters)
    {
        if(parameters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        if(parameters.Length != 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("action");

        _action((T)parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

In your third class you would have the list of `IActionExecutor`s:

```
List<IActionExecutor> _subscriptions;
```

And you would use it like this:

```
public void Execute(params object[] parameters)
{
    var matchingSubscriptions =
        _subscriptions.Where(x => x.CanExecuteForParameters(parameters);
    foreach(var subscription in matchingSubscriptions)
        subscription.Execute(parameters);
}
```

To simplify the creation of those ActionExecutor instances, you can provide a factory class:

```
public static class ActionExecutor
{
    public IActionExecutor Create(Action action)
    {
        return new ActionExecutor(action);
    }

    public IActionExecutor Create<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        return new ActionExecutor<T>(action);
    }

    public IActionExecutor Create<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action)
    {
        return new ActionExecutor<T1, T2>(action);
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

Usage would now be like this:

```
_subscriptions.Add(ActionExecutor.Create(a));
_subscriptions.Add(ActionExecutor.Create(b));
_subscriptions.Add(ActionExecutor.Create(c));
```

Comment: Although this works; OP needs to create multiple ActionExecutors. Then instead of creating multiple classes, he may just rewrite different subscription classes for each Action type deriving from same interface or base class; and I do believe the effort will be less.

Comment: @daryal: What I called `ActionExecutor` is what he called `Subscription`. The effort will be the same. The point is: If you want type safety, you need to create one class per action delegate.

Comment: I do agree that he needs to create a class per action delegate; but it is better for him to create a Subscription class for each action delegate; not an executor class.

Comment: @daryal: That is the same.